# JavaScript split method remove first 2 sections

Tags: javascript, split

I have a variable like this:

```
GA1.2.721553813.2630350365
```

I would like to remove the `GA1.2.` from this string. I am using the `split` method to split this by `.` the issue is that the variable won't always have the 3rd `.` so I want to factor my JavaScript to just return whatever comes after the 2nd `.` how would I do that?

```js
var string = "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365";

// This returns 721553813, I want it to return everything after the second .
var split = string.split('.')[2];

console.log(split);
```

Comment: Looks like a regex would be your best bet. Can we assume that not every string begins with `GA1.2`?

Comment: @j08691 correct, the numbers will not always be exactly that, but I do always want to get everything that comes after the 2nd `.`. So the prefix might be `GA1.1.` for example.

Comment: Maybe this: `string.split('.').slice(2).join(".")` can improve your current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the first part.

```js
var string = "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365",
    result = string.replace(/^([^.]+\.){2}/, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `.slice`

```js
var string = "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365";

var split = string.split('.').slice(2).join('.');

console.log(split);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take all the split results after the second and join them back to a string.

```js
var string = "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365";
var split = string.split('.').slice(2).join('.');
console.log(split);
```

However, a regex would be the simpler option here:

```js
var string = "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365";
var split = string.replace(/^([^.]*[.]){2}/, '');
console.log(split);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will do what you want to do

```
console.log(string.split('.').slice(2).join('.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression.

```
var string = "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365";

// Always assume GA1.2.
var matchesA = string.match(/GA1\.2\.(.+)/);

console.log(matchesA);
console.log(matchesA[1]);

// more generic:
// G(digit).(digit).
var matchesA = string.match(/GA\d\.\d\.(.+)/);

console.log(matchesB);
console.log(matchesB[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is always going to be "GA1.2." (i mean the length is 6) then you can do a sub string on the variable .substr(6).

If its always "GA1.2." you can do a replace("GA1.2.", "")

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to find the `index` related to the second (2nd) `dot` using [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and then [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the string from that index on.

```js
let tests = [
  "GA1.2.721553813.2630350365",
  "LM15.299.721553813313612783",
  "GA33.1.721553813.26.3224",
];

const getCustomSubstr = (str) =>
{
    let idxOf2ndDot = str.indexOf(".", str.indexOf(".") + 1);
    return str.slice(idxOf2ndDot + 1);
};

tests.forEach(t => console.log(t + " => " + getCustomSubstr(t)));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```